# OpenMP create coupled continious tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading, task, openmp, message-queue

I have a complex problem I'm thinking about using OpenMP for however I'm not sure it will work as required.

Basically I have two layers of parallelism in my problem outer and inner sections, the inner sections are ideal for OpenMP, in fact doing so with conventional threads would be overly complicated compared to OpenMP, and require manual balancing. Where are the outer section is more suited to conventional threads and I'm not sure OpenMP is suitable. Finially I need the application to run correctly with out OpenMP, or running OpenMP but with a single thread.

The Outer problem is a set of several tasks the main ones A and B, and secondary ones C and D

The inner problem is loops over items in both A and B with variable computational costs, where A is high priority but B is low priority.

The basic structure is

task A:

```
while True:
    pull current StateB
    update StateA based on StateB
    push StateA
```

task B:

```
while True:
    pull current StateA
    update StateB based on StateA
    push StateB
```

task C and D:

```
while True:
    wait for new StateA
    pull StateA
    update LocalState based on StateA
    export LocalState
```

Note for single thread the order should be

```
while True:
    update StateA based on StateB
    update LocalState based on StateA
    export LocalState
    update StateB based on StateA
```

So C and D will execute after A pushes its state, then wait for new state, and should be faster then A.
While A and B both run as fast as possible checking for new state from the other, and fetching it if it exist then updating their own state and pushing that state to make the changes available to the other the key being that neither should wait for new state from the other, rather use old state in their is no new state.

Now the problem with OpenMP in my understanding is if there is less than 4 threads each task has an internal loop and keeps going until stopped then the task interact by exchanging data. My understanding of how OpenMP dose tasks is that if there is a single thread it will execute them sequentially same for if the compiler doesn't support OpenMP

Note I'm working in C++,

So my actually question is Can I get this to work only using OpenMP, I know I could use native thread or a wrapper around native threads with out a problem, however I want to use OpenMP in the loops for `Update StateA` and `Update StateB` I like OpenMP for this as it makes the thread load balancing at lot easier. However I want to use the same system for the outer section not mix OpenMP and native threads.

I suspect that what I'm looking for isn't possible, but am hoping that someone here may know of a way of managing this.

Comment: Look at Threading Building Blocks (TBB) and the flow::graph in particular.